# filters in ruby

Tags: ruby

How do you make a filter in ruby? I know the function already exists in rails but how do we code it in a ruby program? Here is the program:

```
module Filter
  def before_filter *args   
  end
  def after_filter *args  
  end 
end  

class Ingredient  
  def one
    puts "in one"
  end

  def two
    puts "in two"
  end

  def three
    puts "in three"
  end

  def four
    puts "in four"
  end

  extend Filter

  before_filter :one, :two 
  after_filter :four
end

dish1 = Ingredient.new 
dish1.three
```

Comment: Do you want to learn how is it implemented in Rails controllers or just get something done? If the latter, can you provide a more meaningful example or describe what are you trying to do more precisely? Filters make sense in controllers (before_filter can halt the request), but what does this mean in ingredients?

Comment: @JoshuaCheek: They're apparently getting rid of that tag: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/trogdor-ate-my-homework-tag

Answer (score 1):

Rails can get away with this because they control how the methods get invoked. But here, you're directly calling three from the outside.

To fit within the constraints you've presented, any code which does this will be utterly grotesque. Also, what does the after filter do? Does it determine the return value?

I have implemented something similar to this, though with a slightly different interface that saves it some of the grotesqueness, but still, it's terrible. https://gist.github.com/3450271

Furthermore, there's an obvious question of why you would ever need such a thing.

Comment: when we call an instance method..all the methods in the befor:filter sgould execute first and then the function we called,, after that, the functions written in the after_filter should execute.